# Implementing Finite State Machine for BLE in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy, state-machine, dfa

I'm building a finite state machine in Kotlin to handle BLE state management. I know Tinder has a DSL library for FSM but I'm looking to write something on my own.

Here's what I have so far.

FSM's state and actions are represented using sealed classes. For example, a BLE device can be in **Connected** or **Disconnected** state - each of which in turn would have sub-states (a **Connected** state could mean it's in one of **ReadingCharacteristic**, **WritingCharacteristic**, **SubscribingToCharacteristic** or simply **Idle**)

```
sealed class BleState {
    sealed class Connected : BleState() {
        object Idle : Connected()
        object ReadingCharacteristic : Connected()
        object WritingCharacteristic : Connected()
        object SubscribingToCharacteristic : Connected()
    }
    object Error: BleState()
}
```

The actions are also represented using sealed classes.

```
sealed class BleOperation {
    data class Connect(val bleDevice: BleDevice) : BleOperation()
    object ConnectionCompleted : BleOperation()
    .
    .
    data class Disconnect(val bleDevice: BleDevice) : BleOperation()
    object ErrorOccurred : BleOperation()
}
```

What I need is a way to represent the transitions. Should this be something like a table/2-D array? Should this be a map of <State, List(Events)> where each state would list all possible events that it can accept? Or do I model Transition as a class with properties like currentState, action & newState? I need to be able to ensure that the transitions are valid.

Comment: I have been able to successfully handle BLE events with XState in the browser (thinking about extending my SDK up to Node.js). @nsk's answer seems very appealing to me because I try to port the same concepts and align the teams (mobile, web app, edge computing) on a single Model (Actor based / Hiererchical State Machines) ... How are your progresses on this ?

Answer (score 0):

I don`t think that Tinder library will completely fit your needs. BLE api is rather complicated, so I suppose that you may need nested and parallel states support.

I think that OOP way is that state should have a list/set of its transitions. And transition parameters are:

- event that triggers this transition;
- mandatory source state;
- optional target state or a function which may calculate it.

You can take a look at my library source code:
https://github.com/nsk90/kstatemachine

Comment: Hi @nsk, thanks for your contribution to the open source community ... do you have by any chance successfully handled Jetpack Compose UI / Navigation through a State Machine ? any samples ?

Comment: Hi @AlanHortz! I am not familiar with Jetpack Compose. Regarding Navigation, I have used state machine for cases where sequential dialogs (like permission requests) should be shown to a user (it helps a lot). In general case I think you may need some kind of history of previous states, to perform back navigation. Currently I do not have such functionality.

Comment: Hi @nsk, sorry for the delay of my answer. I think I have cracked the nut regarding how to decouple state from the UI. I am going to look at your implementation. Tx.

Comment: UI should listen to state changes and perform updates to preview current state to a user.

Comment: @AlanHortz take a look a this sample. It is incomplete but it should help you. https://github.com/nsk90/android-kstatemachine-sample

Comment: Thank you I'll give it a shot !